# Pokemon Go Not Working

Tags: pokemon-go

Pokemon Go has stopped working for me and whenever I catch a Pokemon they give 1 or 2 shakes in the Pokeball. It then 100% poofs in a cloud of smoke. WHY?

Answer (score 0):

Right now pokemon Go servers are not stable and have lot of known issues. May be you have to wait for a while until the bug fixes happen